# beforeupdate sequelize não funciona

Tags: express.js, sqlite3, bcrypt, sequelize-js

Estou tentando fazer com que na atualização dos dados sejá encryptado a senha do usuário porém simplismente não funciona e nem emite erro. Tenha a seguinte model do **sequelize**.

```js
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export default (sequelize, DataType) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },

    name: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validation: {
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
    jobTitle: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validation: {
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },

    login:{
      type:DataType.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
      validation:{
        notEmpty:true
      }
    },

    password:{
      type:DataType.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
      validation:{
        notEmpty:true
      },
    },
  },
{
  hooks:{
    beforeCreate: user => {
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
      user.set('password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt))
    },
    beforeUpdate: user => {      
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
      user.set('password', bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt))
    },
  },
  classMethods:{
    isPassword:(encodedPassword, password) => bcrypt.compareSync(password, encodedPassword)
  }
});
  return Users;
}
```

No **create** funciona perfeitamente, porém no update nem executa a atualização.

Answer (score 0):

O `beforeUpdate` depende da forma que é realizado o update, pois só funciona no `instance.save()` ou `instance.update(values)`.

Para `model.update(values, options)` utilize `beforeBulkUpdate`.